# Django count objects created in current month

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have field in my model:

```
class Order(BaseModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to count all Order objects created in current month.
How can I do this in my views?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The (current) accepted answer is incorrect. As stated in comments, maybe OP wants current month in current year. Not current month in any year. Well most people want the first.

So I would rather do

```
Order.objects.filter(created_at__gte=timezone.now().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0))
```

The above also gets around timezone issues.

Comment: `timezone.localdate().replace(day=1)` to get the timezone aware month. timezone can be found in `from django.utils import timezone`

Answer (score 18):

One of possible ways.

```
from datetime import datetime
current_month = datetime.now().month

Order.objects.filter(created_at__month=current_month)
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#month for reference.

Comment: This will fetch last year's records of the same month too. Eg. April, 2016; April, 2015, etc...
Shouldn't we pass the year too if we want just the current month's records since OP asked specifically for current month?

Answer (score 5):

If you're only after the current month, it's easy, because you don't have to worry about an end date - nothing can be created after now, after all.

```
start_of_month = datetime.date.today().replace(day=1)
orders_this_month = Order.objects.filter(created_at__gte=start_of_month)
```

Comment: In Django 1.6, there's an error in start_of_month, 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'today'.

Answer (score -1):

This worked best on my side by adding `.count` operation

```
import datetime

Order.objects.filter(created_at__gte=datetime.datetime.today().replace(day=1, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)).count()
```

Comment: `objects.objects` is wrong. please be sure to use the right syntax in aswers

Comment: Where have i written objects.objects ? @MassimoCosta

Comment: if you check the history of the answer you'll see that at the beginning there was a typo that has been fixed after my comment. for the record the typo was made (and fixed) by @gabriel-innocent-okello